# how can I access my damaged ethereum presale .json file?

Tags: cryptography, ethereum, cryptocurrency, recovery

I’m having issues with accessing my ETH presale even though seems like I’m using the right password. Anyone dealt with that? Is it possible for it to be damaged in any way?

I’ve tried opening the original ETH presale .json file and still got nothing.

Answer (score 0):

JSON file is unlikely to be damaged. You can read it in a text editor, as JSON is a plain text format, and confirm this yourself.

It's likely you are just getting the password wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to run ethereum2john.py to generate a hash with it?

If you try from github
https://github.com/openwall/john/blob/bleeding-jumbo/run/ethereum2john.py

If this out gives you an output like:  $ethereum$w*f1d8a12f5f70... its most likely OK

if you need help try to check this guide on how to recover an ethereum presale wallet: https://medium.com/@keychainx/how-to-recover-ethereum-presale-wallet-b153e83e6c76

Good luck!